# Why are indulgences ever needed for oneself?

Tags: catholicism, confession, judgment, indulgence, penance

Like crimes in legal systems, sins have two consequences: they make me guilty (the conviction) of trespassing God's law, and they involve a punishment (the sentence) for such trespassing. In the Sacrament of Penance, my conviction is removed through the forgiveness of Christ, whereas the penance give to me by the priest commutes my punishment.

Thus, if one participates in the Sacrament of Penance throughout his life, and is judged worthy to go to Heaven in the Particular Judgment, there should be no need for Purgatory.

I understand one can gain Indulgences for others, who perhaps did not have their sins forgiven and sentences paid for during their life on Earth. But if we pay all our penances on Earth, what is the personal use of indulgences? Is it a kind of insurance for, say, one dies unexpectedly, without having confessed some sins?

Comment: The penance assigned in confession may be far less than the temporal punishment for the sins that were confessed.

Comment: @AndreasBlass But, shouldn't priests then give penances that commute completely the temporal punishment? Christ gave to Peter the power to bind or unloose at will.

Comment: Two reasons come to mind (but there may be others I'm not thinking of just now.) First, the priest doesn't know how much temporal punishment will be required for these sins. That's something only God can decide, and He'll take into account all the relevant information about the sins' and sinner's circumstances, information that may not even be known to the penitent, let alone to the priest. Second, if priests assigned such large penances as to commute all temporal punishment for our sins, those penances could scare many of us away from ever going to confession.

Comment: I think [this answer to a related question](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/46817/10672) can help us understand better the purpose of indulgence, as a complement to @KenGraham's answer.

Answer (score 3):

**Why are indulgences ever needed for oneself?**

***Sin has consequences!*** Just because **”one participates in the Sacrament of Penance throughout his life”**, this is no guarantee that all the temporal punishment due to sin has been remitted completely. In fact, this is impossible to know before one’s death. Thus gaining an plenary indulgence just before one’s death is of great importance. And seeing that we never know the moment of our deaths, the practice of gaining plenary indulgences is a wholesome spiritual practice that should be maintained in our spiritual life.

> Sin has two consequences, or punishments (CCC 1472). The first is eternal punishment, in which the soul loses heaven and is confined to an eternity in hell. This punishment is remitted through the forgiveness of sins. The second is temporal punishment, in which a person must expiate, or make reparation for his sins. This temporal punishment remains even after sin is forgiven."
>
> "How does one expiate his sins? The Catholic Church has traditionally identified three major ways–prayer, fasting, and almsgiving. Any good work or sacrifice expiates sin, as well as patiently bearing our sufferings and offering them up in satisfaction for our sins (CCC 1459-1460)."
>
> "What happens if one has not fully expiated his sins before dying? Such a person, before going to heaven, would have to expiate his sins in purgatory (CCC 1030), where love for God is perfected through our sufferings there. Traditionally, the sufferings of purgatory have been compared to a "consuming fire" (1 Cor. 3:11-15). Because certain sins can be forgiven "in the age to come" (Matt. 12:32), Catholics have always prayed for the dead–for the relief of their souls, or their speedy deliverance, if they are in purgatory, for "it is a holy and wholesome thought to pray for the dead, that they may be loosed from their sins" (2 Macc. 12:46)." - [Temporal Punishment and Sin](https://www.catholic-forum.com/members/catholictracts/tract117.html).

It is impossible to know if the consequences of our sins have been fully expiated prior to one’s death; thus indulgences will always have a special place in our spiritual warfare against sin and the snares of the Devil. Until the absolute moment of death, the Devil and his minions will always try to make souls fall into sin. This is why the practice of frequent confession and the practice of obtaining (plenary) indulgences are so important.

Indulgences are a remission of temporal punishments due to sin which have been sacramentally confessed and then absolved, thus making our purification in purgatory shorter. Indulgences do not affect consequences of sin, like gaining HIV from fornication!

Here are some general guidelines for gaining indulgences from the [Apostolic Penitentiary](https://www.vatican.va/roman_curia/tribunals/apost_penit/documents/rc_trib_appen_pro_20000129_indulgence_en.html) of the Vatican.

> General Remarks On Indulgences
>
> 1. This is how an indulgence is defined in the Code of Canon Law (can. 992) and in the *Catechism of the Catholic Church* (n. 1471): "An indulgence is a remission before God of the temporal punishment due to sins whose guilt has already been forgiven, which the faithful Christian who is duly disposed gains under certain prescribed conditions through the action of the Church which, as the minister of redemption, dispenses and applies with authority the treasury of the satisfactions of Christ and the saints".
> 2. In general, the gaining of indulgences requires certain prescribed conditions (below, nn. 3, 4), and the performance of certain prescribed *works* (nn. 8, 9, 10 indicate those specific to the Holy Year).
> 3. To gain indulgences, whether plenary or partial, it is necessary that the faithful be in the *state of grace* at least at the time the indulgenced work is completed.
> 4. A *plenary indulgence* can be gained only *once a day*. In order to obtain it, the faithful must, in addition to being in the state of grace:
>
>    - have the interior disposition of *complete detachment from sin, even venial sin*;
>    - *have sacramentally confessed* their sins;
>    - *receive the Holy Eucharist* (it is certainly better to receive it while participating in Holy Mass, but for the indulgence only Holy Communion is required);
>    - *pray for the intentions of the Supreme Pontiff*.
> 5. It is appropriate, but not necessary, that the sacramental Confession and especially Holy Communion and the prayer for the Pope's intentions take place on the same day that the indulgenced work is performed; but it is sufficient that these sacred rites and prayers be carried out within several days (about 20) before or after the indulgenced act. Prayer for the Pope's intentions is left to the choice of the faithful, but an "Our Father" and a "Hail Mary" are suggested. One sacramental Confession suffices for several plenary indulgences, but a separate Holy Communion and a separate prayer for the Holy Father's intentions are required for each plenary indulgence.
> 6. For the sake of those legitimately impeded, *confessors* can commute both the work prescribed and the conditions required (except, obviously, detachment from even venial sin).
> 7. Indulgences *can* always *be applied either to oneself or to the souls of the deceased*, but they cannot be applied to other persons living on earth.

Comment: So "quantity" of penance in confession might not "cover" the properly assigned temporal punishment by God? I thought by definition, since Jesus gave Peter the power to loose and unloose on Heaven here on Earth, penance would commute completely the temporal punishment. Is this the fault of priests then?

Comment: @luchonacho, no, it is NOT the fault of the priests. The power of keys is what enables indulgences as a means of satisfaction for temporal punishment. The penance assigned in confession may relieve temporal punishment at least in part, but it is primarily assigned as a part of the sacrament to show penance for the sins confessed. It cannot absolutely cover all temporal punishment related to the sins confessed because the actual merit is dependent on the person's subjective state which the priest has no way to know precisely.